# Download File from Amazon s3. Download succees but File Empty

Tags: php, laravel, amazon-s3

I tried to download file from amazon s3 to local storage. Download success, file appear in local storage but the file is empty no content. Looks like missed something in the Code. Need your help friends. Thanks in Advance

here's the code :

```
<?php

namespace App\Console\Library;

require 'vendor/autoload.php';

use Aws\S3\S3Client;
use Aws\S3\Exception\S3Exception;
use Storage;


class DownloadAWS 
{
    public function downloadFile(){

        $s3_file = Storage::cloud()->url('Something.jsonl');
        $s3      = Storage::disk('local')->put('Order.jsonl', $s3_file);

    }
}
```

Comment: Which file format  you are trying to download?

Comment: jsonl file format

Comment: Uploading a file into s3 works fine?  Check it again in s3 . If you configured it correctly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
require 'vendor/autoload.php';

use Aws\S3\S3Client;
use Aws\S3\Exception\S3Exception;

$bucket = '*** Your Bucket Name ***';
$keyname = '*** Your Object Key ***';

$s3 = new S3Client([
    'version' => 'latest',
    'region'  => 'us-east-1'
]);

try {
    // Get the object.
    $result = $s3->getObject([
        'Bucket' => $bucket,
        'Key'    => $keyname
    ]);

    // Display the object in the browser.
    header("Content-Type: {$result['ContentType']}");
    echo $result['Body'];
} catch (S3Exception $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage() . PHP_EOL;
```

Answer (score 1):

Currently, you are retrieving an URL to the s3 file and you are putting it in a file. Your code should currently create a file `Order.jsonl` containing the link to the s3 file.

What you really seem to want is *getting* the file and storing it locally. You can achieve this with the following code:

```
public function downloadFile()
{
    $s3_file = Storage::cloud()->get('Something.jsonl');
    $s3      = Storage::disk('local')->put('Order.jsonl', $s3_file);
}
```

The only difference is using `get()` vs. `url()`.